# Type Initializer

Tags: c#

I've got a config class:

```
namespace SomeCompanyName.SomeAppName
{
    public static class MyConfigClass
    {
        public static readonly string ConsKey = Config.GetAppConfigSetting("ConsKey");
        public static readonly string ConsSecret = Config.GetAppConfigSetting("ConsSecret");
     }
}
```

I've got a method trying to use some of these values in a dictionary:

```
public HttpWebResponse SomeMethod(....)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> headerParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {Constants.Cons, MyConfigClass.ConsumerKey},
        {Constants.Token, MyConfigClass.SingleAccessToken},
        {Constants.ignatureMethod, Constants.SignatureMethodTypeHMACSHA1},
        {Constants.Timestamp, HttpUtility.GenerateTimeStamp()
    };
}
```

For some reason I'm getting this error:

> "The type initializer for 'SomeAppConfig' threw an exception."

Can't figure out why if the SomeAppConfig class is static.

UPDATE:

Here's the definition of GetAppConfigSetting:

```
public class Config
{
    public static string GetAppConfigSetting(string configKey)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey] ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Here's the app.config in my Test project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConsKey" value="HHGRT6jV4M" />
    <add key="ConsSecret" value="QR47dbduycAc" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type initializer of a static class is the code that sets the values of its static variables. In your case, it is this code:

```
public static readonly string ConsKey = Config.GetAppConfigSetting("ConsKey");
public static readonly string ConsSecret = Config.GetAppConfigSetting("ConsSecret");
```

Make sure that `GetAppConfigSetting` can access `ConsKey` and `ConsSecret` without a problem. The exception thrown from the initializer should have more information to help you debug the issue.

Comment: I have used the GetAppConfigSetting utility method before.  So I don't get why now all of a sudden it doesn't work.  I've got the config values in the app.config of my unit test project.  The code that's got the dictionary is in another project so my unit test is calling that code so it should be hitting my unit test project's app.config to get the values...I've done this before but not sure why not it would complain doing this in another project.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Could you post a stack trace for the exception? It has the info you need to diagnose the problem.

Comment: sure, let me take a look.  Meanwhile I've updated the post to show the implementation of the GetAppConfigSetting() method.

Comment: the inner error is "The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element. (C:\\www\Playground.Tests\\bin\\Debug\\Playground.Tests.dll.config line 4)"}"

Comment: @CoffeeAddict It is an issue with your configuration file then: somehow the app.config in your unit tests has a section the config reader does not understand. Try making a small unit test that reads the configuration to see what is going on.

Comment: Ok duh, problem was I had the key name wrong in the config.  Good God.  It's right in the update above but I had it wrong to begin with...

Answer (score 2):

That means there was an exception in the static constructor. In this case, your property initializers. Perhaps the config keys you seek don't exist.

Comment: yep that's what it was...had a wrong key name that I overlooked in my .config.  I guess I need to go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code

```
Constants.ignatureMethod, Constants.SignatureMethodTypeHMACSHA1}
```

It's should be

```
Constants.SignatureMethod, Constants.SignatureMethodTypeHMACSHA1}
```